# Can you hide an html div with jQuery/Javascript when the page is scrolled to a certain number of pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, hide

I have a div that is fixed position that I want hidden once the page is scrolled to a certain position. Is there any way to do this with jQuery/Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, something like this should do the trick:

```
var max_scroll = 300;
$(document).scroll(function(){
  if($(this).scrollTop() >= max_scroll)
  {
      $('#my_div').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, so if you wanted it to be scrolling in a certain div with an id of `wrapper` instead of the document how would you do that? I tried  `$('#wrapper').scroll(function(){
  if($(this).scrollTop() >= maxScroll)
  {
      $('#teasers').fadeOut();
  }
});` , but it didn't work. `#teasers` is the div I want hidden.

Comment: It will if you have your CSS setup correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/efxrC/

Comment: @Sinetheta hmm... I see what you mean. Could you check out http://mywebclass.org/~stephen. It is made for mobile so it will be weird scrolling on the wrapper, but if you use your mouse like you would your finger it does ok.

Comment: Yep I see the application. This should be very simple to integrate :)

Comment: @AlienWebguy Ok, well I tried integrating it (see javascript.js), but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop()>100){
        $("#myElement").hide();
    }
}
```

edit: Oop, I see someone already posted a working solution,